# Function inside an object cannot access that object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, canvas, requestanimationframe

I am trying to move a cicle through a set of points like inside a pipe in horizontal or vertical direction

I am using a function inside an object and trying to call another function of the same object.

```
var ParticleGen = function() {
    this.pipeBegin = points[pipeIndex];
    this.pipeEnds = points[pipeIndex + 1];
    this.begin = function(){
        var pipeBegin = points[pipeIndex];
        var pipeEnds = points[pipeIndex + 1];
        nx = pipeBegin.x;
        ny = pipeBegin.y;
        if(pipeBegin.x == pipeEnds.x && pipeBegin.y >= pipeEnds.y){
            if(ny > pipeEnds.y) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
                drawCircle(nx, ny);
                ny--;
                nx = nx;
            }else if(ny == pipeEnds.y){
                cancelAnimationFrame(animloop);
                this.callBegin();
            }   
            requestAnimFrame(animloop);
        }
        animloop();
    }
    this.callBegin = function(){
        if(pipeIndex <= 3){
            pipeIndex++;
        }
        this.begin();
    }
};
```

But it throws an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'callBegin'
```

The code snippet can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Chanchalstack/PZCpf/)

Thank you,

Comment: Where is your callBegin() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're calling `this.callBegin` isn't the function you think: you're within another function (`animloop` or `animloop1` etc) when you make the call (lines 63 and 78 respectively). Within those functions, [the scope is changed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) and the `this` keyword then refers to the function `animloop` (not `ParticleGen` or `window`). `animloop` has no property `callBegin` (function or otherwise).

You should first 'save' the `ParticleGen` scope to use it within the sub-functions:

```
var ParticleGen = function() {

    var pg = this;

    // etc

    function animloop() {

        // etc

        pg.callBegin();

    }
}
```

An updated, working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PZCpf/2/

Comment: Thank you. It worked..
But Not like i wanted...
The updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Chanchalstack/PZCpf/4/)

Comment: What exactly were you aiming for? This solves your scope-resolution problem and executes your animation loops as they are

Comment: Actually i have a set of points which when connected forms like pipes connected horizontally and vertically. My aim is to move the circle through the points / pipes.This Answer worked and i have no errors on my console now.But the if condition is also not working properly. I am new to this.thats y...
I have the last updated fiddle [here..](http://jsfiddle.net/Chanchalstack/PZCpf/11/)
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

The code in the jsfiddle is different from what you posted.

In the jsfiddle, you have:

```
    if (pipeBegin.x == pipeEnds.x && pipeBegin.y >= pipeEnds.y) {
        // endpoint y greater than start point y moving upwards
        function animloop() {
            if (ny > pipeEnds.y) {
                console.log(nx + " : nx, ny : " + ny)
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
                drawCircle(nx, ny);
                ny--;
                nx = nx;
            } else if (ny == pipeEnds.y) {
                console.log(this)
                cancelAnimationFrame(animloop);
                this.callBegin();
            }
            requestAnimFrame(animloop);
        }
        animloop();

    }
```

You use `this.callBegin()` inside the function `animloop`, then `this` will refer to the global object `window`.

You could change `animloop();` to `animloop.call(this);` or `animloop.apply(this);` to bound the right `this`.

Comment: I cut the code from the fiddle for reader's convenience.But it worked other way.. 
Yes now it is referring to global object window but the suggested change also didnt work. The updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Chanchalstack/PZCpf/1/)
Thank you